# Android - Smart Banner - width not sufficient (always one pixel missing)

Tags: android, smartbanner

I want to add a SMART_BANNER at the bottom of my Android App (HTML5), the layout is defined as follows

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:paddingLeft="0dp"
> android:paddingRight="0dp"
> android:background="@color/default_header"
> >
> <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
>     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:id="@+id/adView"
>     android:background="@color/add_background"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:paddingLeft="0dp"
>     android:paddingRight="0dp"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>
>     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
>     ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner">
> </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
> <WebView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
>     android:background="@color/start_background"
>     android:id="@+id/webView" />
> ```

It works perfectly fine with "BANNER" but in case of a "SMART_BANNER" always with is always one pixel to small and the following error is shown:

W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 412x90 dp, but only has 411x750 dp.
W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 412x90 dp, but only has 
411x750 dp.

**Question:** Where did I lose the one dp (from 412 to 411)?

**Add info:** I am using an emulator (from Android Studio). 
Using issue occurs if I use a 'Pixel 2XL API 26' (SMART banner not shown), but the banner is correctly shown if I use a 'Pixel API 28'

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: I still have the issue. But it seem it it device specific (I am using currently an emulator). Issue occurs with Pixel 2XL (here only the Banner is shown (no smart banner)), but works fine with 'Pixel'. Unfortunately I do not own a Pixel 2XL.

Might the issue be caused by the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the AdView's width to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`. At least that's what I do with my AdViews and it always works regardless if it's a BANNER or SMART_BANNER.

[Off-topic] I've also noticed that on your WebView you wrote `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"`. In this case you don't need to declare a new reference to adView since it's already been declared before. So if you simply put `@id/adView` instead of `@+id` it will still work.

Also try removing those paddings (even though it's set to 0) both from your layout and the AdView. There is no need for them from what I see.

Comment: I still have the issue. But it seem it it device specific (I am using currently an emulator). Issue occurs with Pixel 2XL (here only the Banner is shown (no smart banner)), but works fine with 'Pixel'. Unfortunately I do not own a Pixel 2XL.

Might the issue be caused by the emulator?

Comment: Yes, I can guarantee you 99% it's something to do with the emulator because the AdView behaviour tends to be one way with emulators and another with real devices. You can notice that change of behaviour by running your app on an emulator, the AdView will always show "Test ad" even if you're using a real ad unit ID

Answer (score 1):

you should set width and height like this :

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unitid_web">
```